# Calling a FormatCurrency function on multiple textboses

Tags: javascript, formatting, form

I have a function called `FormatCurrency()` which I would like to call on each of the following elements:

```
 TextBoxA
 TextBoxB
 TextBoxC
 ...
 TextBoxN
```

My current function performs the following operation

```
 function formatALL()
 {
      //get the value into var v. call FormatCurrency(v) and store it back
      var v = document.getElementById("TextBoxA_TextBox").value;
  document.getElementById("TextBoxA_TextBox").value = FormatCurrency(v);

      v = document.getElementById("TextBoxB_TextBox").value;
  document.getElementById("TextBoxB_TextBox").value = FormatCurrency(v);        

  v = document.getElementById("TextBoxC_TextBox").value;
  document.getElementById("TextBoxC_TextBox").value = FormatCurrency(v); 

      //etc... all the way til my last TextBox
 }
```

Is it possible to optimize this code?  In other words, does anyone know any slick loops/operations/etc. to perform this same task?

Comment: are you familiar with jQuery?

Comment: yes, jQuery would make this infinitely slicker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can loop through the elements using a for loop:

```
for(var i = 65; i <= 78; i++) {
    var box = document.getElementById("TextBox" + String.fromCharCode(i) + "_TextBox");
    box.value = FormatCurrency(box.value); 
}
```

Comment: Store the fetch into a variable and you're golden.

Comment: This is JavaScript, nothing with a char type and a ++ operator on it...

Comment: @Bergi: Ah good catch. Been jumping around too many languages lately.

Comment: Well I enumerated them with Alphabets since in actuality, they actually don't have any pattern to their names. I should've been more clear in that regards. Let's say that the names are Jon, steve, mike, etc... 

Still this is a good suggestion

Answer (score 3):

You could use a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), which allows you, for example, to select elemts using CSS selectors. In this case you could assign all your elements a class and use:

```
$('.currency-textbox').each(function() {
   $(this).val(FormatCurrency($(this).val()));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

stick all the strings into an array and iterate over them?

something like

```
var myElems=["TextBoxA_TextBox","TextBoxB_TextBox","TextBoxC_TextBox"];
for(var i = 0; i < myElems.list; i++) {
    var v = document.getElementById(i).value;
    document.getElementById(i).value = FormatCurrency(v);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The quickest modification would be to store your elements in a variable:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("TextBoxA_TextBox");
obj.value = FormatCurrency(obj.value);
```

The next step would be to create a loop that repeats the process dynamically and not statically as it is currently configured.

Answer (score 1):

Two strategies: loops and variables.

```
function formatALL() {
    // "A".charCodeAt(0) = 65
    // "N".charCodeAt(0) = 78
    for (var i=65; i<79; i++) {
        var chr = String.fromCharCode(i);
        var el = document.getElementById("TextBox"+chr+"_TextBox");
        el.value = FormatCurrency(el.value);
    }
}
```

It would be easier if you had enumerated your elements with decimal numbers, not alphanumerical characters. If the element ids grew more complicated (less predictable), you'd need to put them in an array and loop over them:

```
function formatALL() {
    var ids = ["Jon", "steve", "mike", ...];
    for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
        var el = document.getElementById(ids[i]+"_TextBox");
        el.value = FormatCurrency(el.value);
    }
}
```

An even better strategy would be to use a class instead of numbered ids (the elements don't seem to be such unique :-)), like "currency" in your case. Then you don't need to adjust the array every time you change something in the page. With a class name, you can use something like `getElementsByClassName("currency")` (or a library equivalent like `jQuery(".currency")`, then iterate over the returned `NodeList`.

Comment: In terms of optimization, I would eliminate the unnecessary container variables.

Comment: What do you mean with "container variable"? The only unnecessary var is "chr", which I've used to improve comprehensibility and readability. Nothing to micro-optimize here.

Comment: He asked what he could do to optimize the code. Even if it's "micro-optimization," creating unneccessary vars is using unnecessary memory.

Comment: The OP wanted to optimize code, not performance. As you can see in @tskuzzy's answer, the line gets too long for SO - that's not "good" code. Depending on your JS knowledge, you might write less code less readable - I might have done the same if it wasn't a answer on a newbies question.

Comment: Well I enumerated them with Alphabets since in actuality, they actually don't have any pattern to their names. I should've been more clear in that regards.

Let's say that the names are Jon, steve, mike, etc...

Comment: @RobertHsu don't that, you will eventually run out of letters

Comment: @RobertHsu: Yes, as I wrote you then would need to use an array (I've added an example for that now).

Answer (score 0):

There are a fews ways to go about it. Since your examining how to create **"slicker"** or **DRY** code, I would assume you would want succinct code, but not illegible? And you would also be willing to change code to get it.

**Note**: Don't Repeat Yourself (**DRY**).

> Here are two ways in which to do it. One uses **ID** (current), and one uses **class** (perhaps more slick).

**Note**: We use Array.from() to create an actual *Array* from the document node list (ES6), or use the polyfill for legacy browsers [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from?v=control)

```js
// If changing the FormatCurrency function is on the table...

function FormatCurrencyWithChange(input){
  // Whatever you do in here, use input.value.
  input.value = '$ ' + (Math.random() * 100).toFixed(2);
}

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("currency")).forEach(FormatCurrencyWithChange);

// OR

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id$="TextBox"]')).forEach(FormatCurrencyWithChange)

// If you cannot change the FormatCurrency function, then you could also wrap it up.
// Also, if it's not a class, then the function name should be camelCase.

function formatCurrency(input){
  input.value = FormatCurrencyNoChange(input.value);
}

function FormatCurrencyNoChange(value){
  // I don't know whats in your function; This one still accepts value.
  return '$ ' + (Math.random() * 100).toFixed(2);
}

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("currency-wrap")).forEach(formatCurrency);
```

```css
input, label {
  display: block;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<label>Text Box A (ID)</label>
<input id="#TextBoxA_TextBox" type="text" />

<label>Text Box B (ID)</label>
<input id="#TextBoxB_TextBox" type="text" />

<label>Currency (CLASS)</label>
<input class="currency" type="text" />

<label>Currency (CLASS)</label>
<input class="currency" type="text" />

<label>Currency (CLASS) Using Wrapper</label>
<input class="currency-wrap" type="text" />

<label>Currency (CLASS) Using Wrapper</label>
<input class="currency-wrap" type="text" />
```